# Selenium, PHPUnit, and AttachFile()

Tags: file-upload, selenium, phpunit

I am currently running Selenium commands through PHPUnit to a remote server. I've run into a problem where I am trying to upload an image to an input form.

In my PHPUnit, I have the command

```
$this->attachFile( 'file', 'file://test.png' );
```

My Selenium server returns an error

```
PHPUnit_Framework_Exception: Response from Selenium RC server for testComplete().
java.lang.RuntimeException: Output already exists: /tmp/selenium2070373138020433468upload.
```

My test.png file is currently only located in the folder where I am executing my .php unit tests from.

How can I properly upload a file through PHPUnit and Selenium and get it to not throw an exception?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had same problem. Then I found this article: http://bitsilearn.blogspot.com/2010/03/selenium-upload-files.html

So instead of using `$this->attachFile('file', 'file://test.png')` i have used:

```
$this->type('file', '/path/to/file');
```

and it works! : )

Answer (score 1):

My bit of experience: path to file must be prefixed with `file://` (used on Windows platform).

Answer (score 1):

The code below works. Give it a try.

```
$this->byName('Name Locator')->value('/home/img/Desert.jpg');
$this->byName()->submit();
sleep(1);
```

Comment: The original question is really old by now. In 2012, Vitek Jezek's answer was probably correct, but in 2016, using phpunit-selenium with Webdriver, this answer is probably what you are looking for.