# Yii PHPUnit selenium remote upload in IE8

Tags: selenium, internet-explorer-8, phpunit

I'm running Yii PHPUnit Selenium tests on a remote Windows VM using IE8.

Most of the tests work fine - but I'm totally stumped about how to handle uploads. I have the file I want to upload available on the remote VM. In all other browsers I'm able to use

`$this->type('field', 'path/to/file');`

But IE8 won't accept the typed input. I've attempted the steps manually, and the input won't allow me to type a path, I have to click the button to open the dialog.

I've also tried using $this->attachFile() (kinda the opposite of [Selenium, PHPUnit, and AttachFile()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7168604/selenium-phpunit-and-attachfile)) and that doesn't work either.

Does anyone have a good solution or workaround for this?

Answer (score 0):

To perform an upload I use (which works fine for me, don't know if it works on a Windows VM) :

```
    $this->byName('FileToUpload')->value('file');
```

Comment: Thanks - but byName doesn't seem to be a valid method - nor does value - guessing we're using different versions. Question updated to reflect that fact I'm using Yii.